# Get the sector size of a drive letter without using fsutil

Tags: hard-drive, powershell, wmi

I need to know how to get the sector size for a drive letter, eg C:, *without* using `fsutil` in a PowerShell script. Batch and VBS are also acceptable.
The `fsutil` tool is perfect for this as it returns the exact data I need:

```
fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo C:
NTFS Volume Serial Number :        0x32946b93946b587d
NTFS Version   :                   3.1
LFS Version    :                   2.0
Number Sectors :                   0x000000003a0b6c84
Total Clusters :                   0x0000000007416d90
Free Clusters  :                   0x00000000010a9da5
Total Reserved :                   0x0000000000002c98
Bytes Per Sector  :                512
Bytes Per Physical Sector :        512
Bytes Per Cluster :                4096
Bytes Per FileRecord Segment    :  1024
--- etc ---
```

*However*, I am using this script in an environment where there are lots of different languages of Windows in use, and Microsoft in their *infinite wisdom* decided to translate the output:

```
fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo c:
NTFS-Volumeseriennummer :          0xdc7ccd5b7ccd3156
NTFS-Version :                     3.1
LFS-Version :                      2.0
Anzahl der Sektoren :              0x0000000004eec7ff
Gesamtzahl Cluster :               0x00000000009dd8ff
Freie Cluster :                    0x000000000059183d
Insgesamt reserviert :             0x000000000000430e
Bytes pro Sektor :                 512
Bytes pro physischem Sektor :      512
Bytes pro Cluster :                4096
Bytes pro Dateidatensatzsegment :  1024
--- usw ---
```

The information I need – bytes per sector – does not appear to be readily available from the WMI such that I can say "give me the data for C:", and attempts to pair disk-level data with volume-level data to try and patch together a query have been unsuccessful.

I'd hard-code the line number to get the data back from, but the amount of data returned from `fsutil` is inconsistent across versions of Windows. Both the examples above were taken from Windows 10 devices, where the data I need is on line 8, but on Windows 7 devices it is on line 7.

Does anyone know of a way for me to get this data such that i18n will not interfere with it? The only alternative is to hard-code the *line number* I need the data from, with accommodations made for the version of Windows I am running, which is too unreliable to consider.

I am looking for the "Bytes per Sector", not the "Bytes per physical sector" value.

Comment: The "Bytes per Sector" only reports the *logical* sector size. This will be almost always 512. Any other size will cause the malfunctioning of many Windows utilities.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2510009/microsoft-support-policy-for-4k-sector-hard-drives-in-windows
-- it can also read 4096 for AF format drives.

Comment: Windows 8+ can basically run in 4K native mode, but not all applications. See the section "Known compatibility issues" in [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2510009/microsoft-support-policy-for-4k-sector-hard-drives-in-windows). I currently see "Bytes per Sector" equal to 512 even on new 10 TB disks, so I believe you will need to make an effort to get a real 4K native disk.

Comment: Notwithstanding, it's important that I can get the information on the offchance the data is not 512. I'd love to assume 512 and be done with it but it'd only bite me eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a command that will get the logical sector size, tested on Windows 7 and
on Windows 10:

```
wmic partition where "DeviceID like '%Disk #0%#0%'" get BlockSize  | findstr /v BlockSize
```

Or for the boot partition:

```
wmic partition where BootPartition=TRUE get BlockSize  | findstr /v BlockSize
```

Or even:

```
wmic partition where (BootPartition=TRUE and Type='GPT: System') get BlockSize  | findstr /v BlockSize
```

The command gets the information for the partition whose `DeviceID` is like
the specified string. The `DeviceID` of the first disk will be
"Disk #0, Partition #0", for the second disk it will be
"Disk #1, Partition #0" etc.
The `findstr` command is required to get rid of the header line.
Elevated permissions are not required for this.

This is the result on my computer:

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you. I tried "wmic partition > textfile.txt" but I wasn't seeing any disk labels in there. That double-hash-zero-percent is witchcraft, would you be able to explain what it's doing?

Comment: It's a primitive form of regex: `%` is a wildcard meaning any string. In CMD you would use `*` instead. It's required since wmic will for some reason not allow a comma inside the parameter, while `DeviceID` contains a comma.

Comment: Got it. So you're using 0,0 as the deviceID. When I use `wmic partition` the large drive (presumably where all my stuff is) is 0,3; is there any (_any_) risk of different partitions on the same physical drive having different block sizes?

Comment: I don't think so, but don't have a a reference for it.

Comment: Unfortunately choosing 0,0 does not guarantee the system drive. Running it on my home machine with 3 HDDs, it shows the largest archive drive with no OS on it as being 0,0. I'm back to square 1 with this.

Comment: If you wish the info for the boot partition, this is easy enough - I added this variant of the command.

Comment: Unfortunately when running this command I am shown two drives. For whatever reason, "BootPartition" is not a useful criterion; my archive drive is listed as a boot drive when it definitely isn't.

Comment: You have a funny archive drive. I suspect it previously contained an operating system. I added one more condition. You can inspect all conditions to find more differences and add them in using `wmic partition where (BootPartition=TRUE and Type='GPT: System') list full`.

Comment: OK, that gets me the boot partition of my system drive. Not the data partition where C: lives, but the same physical disk. Provided we're correct about blocksize being a disk-level setting and not partition-level, this will work fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get them all then select for what you are after.

```
# Using cmd.exe
wmic partition get BlockSize, StartingOffset, Name, Index

# Results

<#
    BlockSize  Index  Name                   StartingOffset
    512        0      Disk #0, Partition #0  1048576
    512        1      Disk #0, Partition #1  472907776
    512        2      Disk #0, Partition #2  594542592
    512        3      Disk #0, Partition #3  508414656512
    512        4      Disk #0, Partition #4  510287413248
    512        0      Disk #1, Partition #0  135266304
    512        0      Disk #3, Partition #0  135266304
    512        0      Disk #2, Partition #0  135266304
#>


$wql = "SELECT Label, Blocksize, Name FROM Win32_Volume WHERE FileSystem='NTFS'"
Get-WmiObject -Query $wql -ComputerName '.' |
Select-Object Label, Blocksize, Name

# Results

<#
Label  Blocksize Name
-----  --------- ----
            4096 \\?\Volume{bba9420f-c375-409b-977a-b7d4f69b18e6}\
Root        4096 C:\
            4096 \\?\Volume{184c6e20-4659-4a3a-89e6-c529c69fe26b}\
            4096 \\?\Volume{3ebf588c-f842-4c69-9a93-2f241231667e}\
Data        4096 D:\
SDN         4096 E:\
EVO4TB      4096 F:\
#>
```

***Update for the OP***

The above and below can be done with or without user interaction.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskPartition | 
  Select-Object -Property Name, BlockSize, Description, BootPartition
```

or WMIC

```
 Start-Process -FilePath powershell `
 -ArgumentList '-NoExit', 'wmic --% partition get BlockSize, StartingOffset, Name, Index'
```

Comment: It is not an interactive script so user intervention cannot be relied on unfortunately

Comment: My response was not specific to interactive anything, It could be used with or without any user interaction. Even that WMIC bit can be done via PowerShell directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output of fsutil to Select-String and search for 'Bytes Per Sector', 'Bytes pro Sektor', and other language variations to get the line with the info you want, irrespective of line number:

```
fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo c: |
    select-string 'Bytes Per Sector|Bytes pro Sektor'
```

You can add additional language strings to the search string using the regular expression 'or' operator (|).

Keith

Comment: It's looking like this is going to be the only way to do it if the WMI isn't going to co-operate. I'm trying not to do it this way. I know if I include 5 languages the deal-breaker will be the sixth I omitted.

Comment: Can you use Get-Culture to determine the language version or output "unrecognized language" if no match is found?

Comment: If I knew which languages I was contending with before the fact it wouldn't be so much of an issue. The problem is that this script is going to be GA, so I really can't be writing out seven thousand different versions of the same text string depending on language ID.